# How can I create a correlation matrix in R without removing null values?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, data-science, correlation

im trying to use correlation matricies in r
my data has bunch of null or n/a values
my current approach is to convert these null values to 0
this works but it results in an inaccurate matrix because some columns that have correlation are overpowered by the 0
do you know of any solution to fix the na values?

Here is my code:

```
mydata = read.csv("exoplanet.csv")
res2 <- cor(mydata[sapply(mydata, function(x) is.numeric(x))])
res2[is.na(res2)] <- 0
corrplot(res2, type = "upper", order = "hclust", 
      tl.col = "black", tl.srt = 45)
```

Here is a workaround I tried:

```
mydata = read.csv("exoplanet.csv")
mydata = lapply(mydata, as.numeric)
mydata = as.matrix(as.numeric(unlist(mydata))) 
//the reason i do this is because otherwise i get a list to double error
```

now when i try to use this graph, i get this error:

```
The matrix is not in [-1, 1]! or In as.dist.default(1 - corr) : non-square matrix
```

Comment: My objective is to create a correlation matrix using my data.
Here is a link to my data https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aUKQSR1MEbGexYL6LeeOMzJP6xLGe2C4/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove columns that has only 1 type of value (excluding NAs):

```
x = read.csv("./Downloads/Exoplanet extract new.csv")
is_num = sapply(x,is.numeric)
not_mono = sapply(x,function(i)length(unique(i[!is.na(i)])))>1
```

Then:

```
cor(x[,is_num & not_mono],use="p")
```

You still have NA cells due to some missing values between some columns, but most likely this is the best you can do.

Comment: ill try this out 
is there a way for r to automatially disregard columns with characters

Comment: Error in hclust(as.dist(1 - corr), method = hclust.method) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 10)
I get this error when using ur method @StupidWolf
this happened to me too thats why i converted to zero

Comment: i looked at your data, not easy.. i think you just have to take top 200 variables without NAs..

Comment: do you know how to do that 
this is one of my first times using r 
do you know a fix to that error